# OpenIddict/OIDC Logout Infinite Loop

Tags: openid-connect, openiddict

I created an OpenIddict auth server for my existing application which uses AspNetCore Identity. The login process works great, but the logout process causes an infinite loop between my app and the auth server. Here's my setup:

`Startup.cs`

```
services.AddAuthentication(options =>
            {
                options.DefaultScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
                options.DefaultChallengeScheme = OpenIddictServerAspNetCoreDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
                options.DefaultSignOutScheme = OpenIddictServerAspNetCoreDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            })
            .AddCookie()
            .AddOpenIdConnect(OpenIddictServerAspNetCoreDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, options =>
            {
                options.SignInScheme = IdentityConstants.ApplicationScheme;
                options.Authority = "https://localhost:44395";
                options.ClientId = "myclient";
                options.ResponseType = OpenIdConnectResponseType.Code;
                options.Scope.Add(Scopes.Profile);
                options.Scope.Add(Scopes.Email);
                options.CallbackPath = "/signin-oidc";
                options.SaveTokens = true;
                options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
                {
                    NameClaimType = Claims.Name
                };
                options.GetClaimsFromUserInfoEndpoint = true;
                options.SignedOutRedirectUri = "/Account/Login";
            });
```

The `Logout()` method in my `AccountController`:

```
[HttpPost, ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Logout()
        {
            await _signInManager.SignOutAsync();
            return SignOut(authenticationSchemes: OpenIddictServerAspNetCoreDefaults.AuthenticationScheme,
                properties: new AuthenticationProperties
                {
                    RedirectUri = "/"
                });
        }
```

The Startup of my auth server:

```
        services.AddAuthentication(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
                .AddCookie(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);

        services.AddControllersWithViews();
        services.AddRazorPages();

        services.AddDbContext<UserDbContext>(options =>
        {
            options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("connection-dev"));
            options.UseOpenIddict();
        });

        services.AddDatabaseDeveloperPageExceptionFilter();

        services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, IdentityRole>()
          .AddEntityFrameworkStores<UserDbContext>()
          .AddDefaultTokenProviders()
          .AddDefaultUI();

        services.AddDistributedMemoryCache();

        services.AddSession(options =>
        {
            options.IdleTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(10);
            options.Cookie.HttpOnly = true;
            options.Cookie.SameSite = SameSiteMode.None;
            options.Cookie.SecurePolicy = CookieSecurePolicy.Always;
        });

        services.Configure<IdentityOptions>(options =>
        {
            options.ClaimsIdentity.UserNameClaimType = Claims.Name;
            options.ClaimsIdentity.UserIdClaimType = Claims.Subject;
            options.ClaimsIdentity.RoleClaimType = Claims.Role;
            options.ClaimsIdentity.EmailClaimType = Claims.Email;
            options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount = false;
        });

        services.AddCors(options =>
        {
            options.AddPolicy("AllowMyOrigins",
                builder =>
                {
                    builder
                        .AllowCredentials()
                        .WithOrigins(
                            ["http://localhost:5000"])
                        .AllowAnyHeader()
                        .AllowAnyMethod();
                });
        });

        services.AddOpenIddict()
            .AddCore(options =>
            {
                options.UseEntityFrameworkCore()
                       .UseDbContext<UserDbContext>();
            })
            .AddServer(options =>
            {
                options.SetAuthorizationEndpointUris("connect/authorize")
                   .SetIntrospectionEndpointUris("connect/introspect")
                   .SetLogoutEndpointUris("connect/logout")
                   .SetTokenEndpointUris("connect/token")
                   .SetUserinfoEndpointUris("connect/userinfo")
                   .SetVerificationEndpointUris("connect/verify");

                options.AllowAuthorizationCodeFlow()
                       .AllowRefreshTokenFlow();

                options.RegisterScopes(Scopes.Email, Scopes.Profile, Scopes.Roles);

                options.AddDevelopmentEncryptionCertificate()
                       .AddDevelopmentSigningCertificate();

                options.UseAspNetCore()
                       .EnableAuthorizationEndpointPassthrough()
                       .EnableLogoutEndpointPassthrough()
                       .EnableTokenEndpointPassthrough()
                       .EnableUserinfoEndpointPassthrough()
                       .EnableStatusCodePagesIntegration();
            })
            .AddValidation(options =>
            {
                options.UseLocalServer();
                options.UseAspNetCore();
            });
```

And the `AuthorizationController.Logout()`: I removed the consent logout part so it should just log the user out right away.

```
[HttpGet("~/connect/logout")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Logout()
    {
        await _signInManager.SignOutAsync();
        return SignOut(
            authenticationSchemes: OpenIddictServerAspNetCoreDefaults.AuthenticationScheme,
            properties: new AuthenticationProperties
            {
                RedirectUri = "/"
            });
    }
```

The post_logout_redirect_uri is http://localhost:5000/signout-callback-oidc.
When I try to logout, it enters an infinite loop like this:
[image]
I think I want it to go back to the auth server's login page on logout. I definitely don't want it circling around forever :).
Here's the requests in table form:
| Method | Endpoint | Status Code | Type | Source |
|--------|----------|-------------|------|--------|
| GET    | http://localhost:5000/Account/Logout | 302 | xhr / Redirect | user-profile.component.ts:42 |
| GET    | logout?post_logout_redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocal…Ib3Ak&x-client-SKU=ID_NET8_0&x-client-ver=7.2.0.0 | 302 | xhr / Redirect | - |
| GET    | https://localhost:44395/connect/logout?post_logout_redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A5000%2Fsignout-callback-oidc&id_token_hint=eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsImtpZCI6IjIzMEYxN0VGRkVBM0RERTFGNTYzNkRCMDcwNzA1NDYxRDExRjk0RkEiLCJ4NXQiOiJJdzhYN182ajNlSDFZMjJ3Y0hCVVlkRWZsUG8iLCJ0eXAiOiJKV1QifQ.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.sTuSjQCxqh89nEqOn-zfykkLiZoB_UOcbE8FHG5_v8sjJHx5Ytn6YxONpQenIjZggDLvXSBs4MBN9oRe2VqQpkFO2i1RBaCIiCfmyYY4YDQ4EiAr3R7Z9TpJ_W-4rHkczlHYsU9WT9OtOfXUOpy1uHQPIRgrDHBScZVMo0Uz0Q9BlU2d0Dg3rs3esRxA3MJJn3fedqQoSYlnBFdRxo-4-szu4krldn4mhkns-ua96pCQWQwIGetFKzhV2MDOzFF5vj38mjwKNw80v4dP-H8Prq1Q8LuzCIXyra8USx6WQVYaQVVb3c_5FxEVCaBCxB-XaZN8lP3Ajw9Ed-KWaXcdgA&state=CfDJ8DwhaUXmuCROpCgfCLIYTwyHz6Z_WecMr8WjPz6O6F48TU3RrqurGDWG2WoOY-Y52iZP5ykUZFDFVFqOL4j8yiARGAVHDLii8h4JD6zFXKf82zGODbRgPYNex7wH8okYB4LUyfQqxyNGjJ9A4lIb3Ak&x-client-SKU=ID_NET8_0&x-client-ver=7.2.0.0 | 204 | preflight | Preflight |
| GET    | logout?post_logout_redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocal…Ib3Ak&x-client-SKU=ID_NET8_0&x-client-ver=7.2.0.0 | 302 | xhr / Redirect | Logout |
| GET    | signout-callback-oidc?state=CfDJ8DwhaUXmuCROpCgfCL…zFXKf82zGODbRgPYNex7wH8okYB4LUyfQqxyNGjJ9A4lIb3Ak | http://localhost:5000/signout-callback-oidc?state=CfDJ8DwhaUXmuCROpCgfCLIYTwyHz6Z_WecMr8WjPz6O6F48TU3RrqurGDWG2WoOY-Y52iZP5ykUZFDFVFqOL4j8yiARGAVHDLii8h4JD6zFXKf82zGODbRgPYNex7wH8okYB4LUyfQqxyNGjJ9A4lIb3Ak | 204 | preflight | Preflight |
| GET    | signout-callback-oidc?state=CfDJ8DwhaUXmuCROpCgfCL…zFXKf82zGODbRgPYNex7wH8okYB4LUyfQqxyNGjJ9A4lIb3Ak | http://localhost:5000/signout-callback-oidc?state=CfDJ8DwhaUXmuCROpCgfCLIYTwyHz6Z_WecMr8WjPz6O6F48TU3RrqurGDWG2WoOY-Y52iZP5ykUZFDFVFqOL4j8yiARGAVHDLii8h4JD6zFXKf82zGODbRgPYNex7wH8okYB4LUyfQqxyNGjJ9A4lIb3Ak | 302 | xhr / Redirect | logout |
| GET    | http://localhost:5000/ | 204 | preflight | Preflight |
| GET    | http://localhost:5000/ | 400 | xhr | signout-callback-oidc |
| GET    | http://localhost:5000/GetXsrfToken | 200 | xhr | user-profile.component.ts:42 |

What could be causing it to keep redirecting to Logout?